# inline html to change li active's color

Tags: html, css

i really need to change active's color just inline html, not using css.
any suggestion guys how to do it

```
<li class="active"><a data-transition-type="backSlide" href="#all" data-toggle="tab" onMouseOver="this.style.color='#0F0'"onMouseOut="this.style.color='#666666'">All</a></li>

<li><a data-transition-type="backSlide" href="#smartphone" data-toggle="tab" onMouseOver="this.style.color='#0F0'" onMouseOut="this.style.color='#666666'">smartphone</a></li>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean you want to change the font color of the li.active?

```
<li style="color:red;">...</li>
```

Or if you do not want to use an external css file you could still use an intern css block like:

```
<style>
  li.active { color: red; }
</style>
```

and put it inside your head-tag. You could read more about in on http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_css.asp

Comment: so if i wanna use method 1 then the code will be <li class="active" style="color:red;"> ??

Comment: if you like red then yes! You can also use # values like color: #ff0000 - also you can add as many styles as you need like style="color: red; font-weight: bold; font-size: larger"

Comment: thank you sir,you are the winner